# setfill and setw python equivalent?

Tags: python, c++, std

I am currently porting some C++ code to python but didn't find out how to translate this:

```
print  std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << myVar << std::dec << " "
```

How do I translate `std::setfill('0')` and `std::setw(2)` to python?

Comment: Didn't look very hard did you...

`'<any_char>'*n` returns any_char n times. `"%x"%myVar` formats myVar as a hex.

Comment: But who'd write anything like this to begin with?  If `myVar` has a semantic such that it requires such formatting, you'd write a single manipulator which does that, to be used with all variables which have that semantics.  (In Python, the only way I can think of off hand to to that is to write a function which does the conversion, using the desired formatting, and returns a string.)

Comment: Also, of course: you wouldn't return the format to `std::dec`; you'd reset it to whatever it was before you changed it.  (This can be done in the destructor of a custom manipulator, or by use of a scoped object which saves the format in its constructor, and restores it in its destructor.)

Comment: Look up ljust and rjust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent, but you can convert each value you want to display with the `format` function. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language for the format specification.

```
print '{:02x}'.format(myVar)
```

Comment: And of course, you'd wrap this in a function, so that the format specifier only occurs once in your program, and is labeled with the logical semantics.

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking for a equivalent to `std::setw(n)`. For the curious, I used `'{:>n}'.format(nbr)`.

Example:

```py
In [13]: '{:>2}'.format(1)
Out[13]: ' 1'
In [14]: '{:>2}'.format(10)
Out[14]: '10'
```